# Difference between @: and <text> in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-2

What's the difference between these 2 in Razor? I find that I can accomplish the same, whether I use `@:` or `<text>`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Scott Guthrie [wrote about both on his blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax). His answer basically boils down to `<text>` supports multiple lines, while `@:` is meant to be a more compact form for a single line.

Comment: So, they're functionally the same?

Comment: @anemaria20 It appears so.